# How to avoid duplicate completion in Bash

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I defined the basic completion script. For program d, it can take subcommand exempt, limit, show, and update.

```
complete -W "exempt limit show update" d
```

However, when I press tab after `d exempt`, bash displays the completion menu again.

```
$ d <tab>
exempt  limit   show    update
$ d exempt <tab>
exempt  limit   show    update
$ d exempt exempt <tab>
exempt  limit   show    update
```

How do I prevent Bash from inserting the same word again and again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you see is the intended behavior when you use the basic completion mechanism `complete -W`.

If you want a more intelligent completion, you need to to write completion functions (see the "Programmable Completion" section in the [Bash manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html)) and use `complete -F`.

Here is how to adapt your example:

```
$ comp_d() {
    COMPREPLY=( $(
        if [ "$COMP_CWORD" -eq 1 ]; then
            compgen -W "exempt limit show update" "$2"
        fi
    ) )
}

$ complete -F comp_d d
```

Such functions must return the completion candidates in an array `COMPREPLY`. I only use your word list when the user is completing the first argument (`COMP_CWORD` is 1), else the array is left empty.

Comment: I don't think many commands accept duplicate options. What a shame bash doesn't support such basic requirements.

Comment: @Gqqnbig Actually, many commands accept duplicate options, but generally the last option takes precedence over the prior ones. So, you are right that this is of little use for the CLI and that would be a good thing that Bash provide an option to automatically discard from the word list words that are already used elsewhere in the command.